# Spring MultipartFile parameter not respecting configured maxFileSize

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a file upload Controller. I'm trying to make the max file size configurable, but I'm not able to figure out why the configuration as documented (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-multipart-file-upload-configuration) is not being applied.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

@Controller
public class FileUploadController {

  private MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement;

  @Autowired
  public FileUploadController(MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement) {
    this.multipartConfigElement = multipartConfigElement;
  }

  @PostMapping("/upload")
  public void upload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(file.getInputStream());
    // TODO something with inputStream

    long fileSize = file.getSize();
    boolean fileSizeLimitExceeded = fileSize > multipartConfigElement.getMaxFileSize();
    return;
  }
}
```

[Debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1looJ.png)

I expect the multipartConfigElement.getMaxFileSize() should prevent larger files getting this far and automatically return a 400 or some other type of exception.

But instead the maxFileSize seems to be completely ignored.

Comment: add this parameter inside the application.property file

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB // change accordingly
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB// change accordingly

Comment: @GaneshGudghe I don't think the configuration is relevant here. The default is 1MB (can be seen in the debug screenshot). For what it's worth setting that property does change the MultipartConfigElement value in my application, but the problem still exists. The problem = the configured spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size does not seem to do anything automatically.

Answer (score 4):

So it turns out that the limits do work, and do automatically throw Exceptions.

I saw this when I ran a request against my Controller using Postman.

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-04-05T09:52:39.839+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "Maximum upload size exceeded; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSizeLimitExceededException: The field file exceeds its maximum permitted size of 1 bytes.",
  "path": "/upload"
}
```

The reason I wasn't seeing that was because I was testing with MockMVC (snippet below). MockMVC doesn't seem to trigger the exceptions for some reason – maybe because it is not running on a compatible web server. Probably related to https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-vs-end-to-end-integration-tests.

```java
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = DemoApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class FileUploadTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Test
  public void givenAFileThatExceedsTheLimit_whenUploaded_responseWith400Error() throws Exception {

    MockMultipartFile file =
        new MockMultipartFile("file", new FileInputStream(TestUtils.loadLargeFile()));

    this.mockMvc
        .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/upload").file(file)
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE))
        .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
  }

}
```

Comment: So @andrew-e, you have any solution for that problem?

Comment: I also would be interested into a solution.

Comment: There was nothing to solve. The application is working as expected, but cannot be tested with MockMvc because MockMvc doesn't replicate the specific behaviour. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-vs-end-to-end-integration-tests

It's been a while since I've looked at this, but I believe you can test with a full running server e.g. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-working-with-random-ports

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Andrew E, MockMvc won't replicate the max file size that you set with the properties `spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size` and `spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size`.

I managed to test the file size limite like this (adapted from here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.with-running-server)

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class RunningServerTest {

  // my upload endpint requires authentication, so I need to mock the Oauth2 authorization server response
  @MockBean private JwtDecoder jwtDecoder;

  @Test
  void shouldNotUploadMultipartFileGreaterThanMaxAllowedSize(@Autowired WebTestClient webClient) {
    // GIVEN
    Jwt jwt =
        Jwt.withTokenValue("some-bearer-token")
            .header("key", "value")
            .claim("email", "user_email@example.com")
            .build();
    when(jwtDecoder.decode("some-bearer-token")).thenReturn(jwt);
    ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource("file-bigger-than-max-size.txt");

    // WHEN + THEN
    webClient
        .post()
        .uri("/upload")
        .header("Authorization", "Bearer some-bearer-token")
        .header("Content-Type", MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
        .body(BodyInserters.fromResource(res))
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus()
        // you might need to define a custom exception handler 
        // to map org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.SizeLimitExceededException 
        // to a 400 http error
        .isEqualTo(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
}
```